# Postgres - update CTE with incrementing values

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have a table with `organization_id` and `name` columns. I need to add a composite unique index to those columns, but we have some duplicate names that need to be updated. I can find the offending records with this query:

```
with cte as (select l.id, t.*
from locations l
join (
  select name, organization_id, count(*) as qty
  from locations
  group by name, organization_id
  having count(*) > 1
) t on l.name = t.name and l.organization_id = t.organization_id )
```

I would like to update the records by appending some some incrementing values to the names (this isn't production data, don't judge me :D).

something like

```
update locations
set name = locations.name || (select i from generate_series(1..some_count))::text
from cte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.blahblah;
```

Then

```
UPDATE
    locations
SET
    name = locations.name || nextval('public.blahblah')
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    locations.id = cte.id;
```

It's safe because

> even if multiple sessions execute nextval concurrently, each will
>   safely receive a distinct sequence value

and

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the
>   same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once
>   a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be
>   returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later
>   aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value.

See [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-sequence.html).

Comment: This worked, just had to add a `where locations.id = cte.id` after the from.

Comment: It's always a pleasure to help ;) I've added `where` clause to the answer.